# Skip fsck at boot

Tags: grub, fsck

I know it is not recommended, but is there a way to skip `fsck` checking the file system mounted at `/` if it was not cleanly unmounted? I want to do this in single instances, while or before booting. I use Linux, Debian 8.3, with GRUB as boot loader and the disk is `ext2`-formatted.

Comment: Interesting question; since fsck has to run before / is mounted, and thus before /etc/fstab is visible, does the fs_passno (6th) field in it change the behavior of fsck on / ?

Comment: Does not the auto-run-at-boot `fsck` give you a few seconds to mash a key to skip this?  I seem to recall this to be the case.

Comment: you used to be able to add `fastboot` to the kernel command line in grub, [see answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239754/119298)

Comment: @meuh: That's the answer which I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `0` (or nothing) on the sixth field of `/etc/fstab` for the root filesystem to disable `fsck` on `/` on next reboot.

For example:

```
UUID=foobar  /  ext4   errors=remount-ro  0  0
```

Again, as you have said this is not recommended absolutely.

---

From `man 5 fstab`:

> The sixth field (fs_passno): 
>                 This field is used by the fsck(8) program to determine the order in which filesystem checks are done at reboot time.  **The
>   root filesystem should be specified with a fs_passno of 1**, and other
>   filesystems should have a fs_passno of  2.   Filesys‐
>                 tems within a drive will be checked sequentially, but filesystems on different drives will be checked at the same time to
>   utilize parallelism available in the hardware.  **If the sixth field is
>   not present or zero, a value of zero is returned and
>                 fsck will assume that the filesystem does not need to be checked.**

Comment: it seems like systemd triggers fsck on all partitions anyway.